# Cat races me when I pace

Tags: cats, behavior

I have a habit of pacing around my apartment, and after a few paces my cat will start sprinting in front of me as I go back and forth. It's annoying because  he'll cross my path and I have to stop in my tracks to avoid kicking him.

Is there a good way I can make him stop doing it?

Comment: The cat wants to be involved in whatever you are doing, and/or wants to lead you toward places where you do things the cat likes, and)or is trying to start a "chase me" game. They never really grow out of any of these, but they do learn to dodge so they aren't kicked or stepped on too often. I think the answer is "you have a cat "